# Magento 1.9.1 rwd : Custom Attribute Filter in Layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, layered-navigation, rwd-theme

I am trying to add Filter attribute called building type for my book store.

Below is Category Structure with product.

```
    + Regional Books(4) 
       - English (2) 
            -- book-1
            -- book-2
       - German (3)
            -- book-3
            -- book-4
```

I have created a custom attribute of type dropdown and have set Filterable with result for Use In Layered Navigation.

[image]

Then configured the custom attribute value in product creation page.

Book-1
[image]

Book-2
[image]

But Still custom attribute is not appearing in layered navigation. 
Parent page only show sub category and tags and products and not my custom filter. Sub category page shows only tags and products list.

[image]

[image]

Parent Category - Display setting
[image]

Any idea why Filter attribute is not appearing in the layered navigation. 
Please advice I am using Magento 1.9.1 CE with default rwd theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're highlighting the answer to your own question. Set Is Anchor to true.